# How to send a message from my Swift UIKIT app to my Watch App in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, timer, uikit, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I just created a watch app target for my already existing app.
I want to set a timer to start on this watch app. It just need to me a timer, decreasing from 60 to 0.

A also have a timer im my ap, and i want to dispatch the timer in the watch also. I want the user to visualize the timer in his watch. I dont need to load the view of my app in the watch, so, i figure in create just a view with a timer, and when the user touches the start timer in the iphone app, the timer will start on the watchOS.

But, when i add the file target, my xcode screams that cannot find the types of the uiKIT.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to only send a message from my app to my watchapp

Comment: Please see [ask], including the section about using text for code, not images. Beyond that, yes, it's true that you can't use UIKit in your watch app. SwiftUI itself (being a UI framework) doesn't have a way to communicate between the watch and the parent app. You should look into things like Watch Connectivity: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity

Comment: I don't know if there is a need to import the class, the point is that I just want to do this communication.

I want the user to click on my app, it triggers a timer on the apple watch.

I created this project in xcode 14.2, went to files, new, add target, and created a watch app for existing iphone app